# What is the correct way to decrease stocks in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock

There is a standard way to decrease stocks in a payment gateway for WooCommerce when we are doing payment processing or blocking stocks for long-lasting payment (Paycheques or so on):

```
wc_reduce_stock_levels( $order_id ); 
WC()->cart->empty_cart();
```

But there are `set_stock_reduced` and `get_stock_reduced` functions also. Is it better to check a reduction status before such dealing with stocks or not?

```
if ( !get_stock_reduced($order_id) ) wc_reduce_stock_levels( $order_id );
WC()->cart->empty_cart();
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec We are talking about an Offline payment in Woo classification [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/).

Comment: This is a correct illustration of offline payment [https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Gateway_Cheque.html#106-134]. But the question is: why do we/developers don't check Decreased flag before stock management in this case?

Comment: This kind of question just gives "primarily opinion-based" answers… This is what stackOverFlow says about: *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."* … So I will not answer, sorry.